# Verilog parameters with parametric width

Tags: verilog, system-verilog

It isn't hard to agree that parametrized module design is a good practice and data width is a good starting point.

I have been defining constants 0 and 1 of required bus or operand widths for years. That to avoid compiler warnings and to explicitly communicate the intention. Typically using something like:

```
parameter   WIDTH = 16;
//  ...
parameter   ZERO  = {WIDTH{1'b0}};            // all zeroes
parameter   UNO   = {{WIDTH-1{1'b0}}, 1'b1};  // all zeroes except LSB
```

This is all fine until I want to define an arbitrary constant with given parametrized WIDTH.
I certainly can write a constant with fixed width - but that's not what I want:

```
parameter   FULL   = 16'd57;
```

However, analogous construct using the parametric WIDTH fails with syntax error:

```
parameter   LEVEL   = WIDTH'd57;   // <== *ERROR*
```

What is the proper syntax - if there is one?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This was a problem in Verilog because the RHS of a parameter assignment was used as the self-determined width of the parameter. SystemVerilog addressed this by allowing you to specify a datatype as part of a `parameter` declaration

```
parameter   WIDTH = 16;
//  ...
parameter bit [WIDTH-1:0] ZERO  = '0;           // all zeroes
parameter bit [WIDTH-1:0] UNO   = 1;  // all zeroes except LSB
parameter bit [WIDTH-1:0] LEVEL = 57;
```

The datatype does not change when overriding.

Another way is using a sizing cast

parameter LEVEL = WIDTH'(56);

But if you do it this way and override the parameter, the datatype becomes the width of the overriding value's type.

Comment: This is fantastic! Thanks.
The datatype specification is a gem.
However, I find the sizing cast relevant too if - as an example - I want to create dependent parameter and use division - as an example:

Comment: `parameter bit [WIDTH-1:0] LEVEL1 = WIDTH'(LEVEL/2-1);`
Note: For simple divide by 2 I may still use `LEVEL>>1` without need for cast.